# Razor Not Rendering HtmlHelper Extension Method Properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a Extension method in my html helper class to render an Autocomplete. This works fine with aspx view engine in VS2008 & VS2010. The Autocomplete class has an overloaded ToString() method which outputs Raw Html.

However when i use Razor engine i don't get any visible output. Firebug shows the output of Extension method is Html Encoded as follow :(with all &lt, &gt..)

```
    &lt;input class="AutoComplete" id="p_ename" name="p_ename" style="width: 190px" type="text" valuefield="p_empid"&gt;&lt;/input&gt; &lt;input id="p_empid" name="p_empid" type="hidden"&gt;&lt;/input&gt; 
&lt;script type='text/javascript'&gt;$('#p_ename').autocomplete('/UserMst/GetEmployee', { dataType: 'json', scroll: true, parse: function(item, event) { $('#p_empid').val(''); var array = new Array(); if(item) for (var i = 0; item[i]; i++ ) { array[array.length] = { data: item[i], value: item[i], result: unescape(item[i].Text) }; } return array; }, formatItem: function(row) { return unescape(row.Text); } }).result(function(event, item, formatted) { $('#p_empid').val(item.Value); }).keyup(function() { if (window.event.keyCode != 13 &amp;&amp; window.event.keyCode != 16 &amp;&amp; window.event.keyCode != 20 &amp;&amp; window.event.keyCode != 9 &amp;&amp; window.event.keyCode != 27 &amp;&amp; !(window.event.keyCode &gt;= 112 &amp;&amp; window.event.keyCode &lt;= 123) &amp;&amp; !(window.event.keyCode &gt;= 37 &amp;&amp; window.event.keyCode &lt;= 40)) { $('#p_empid').val(''); } });
&lt;/script&gt;
```

And this is how I call the method :

```
@Html.AutocompleteFor(m => m.p_empid, m => m.p_ename)
.setUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/UserMst/GetEmployee"))
.setClass("AutoComplete").setStyle("width: 190px")
```

How do i fix this to work with Razor in MVC3 ?

Thanks

Comment: Call `ToMvcHtmlString()` (IIRC)

Comment: @leppie - `ToMvcHtmlString()` is internal to the framework - you need to call `MvcHtmlString.Create()` or write your own extension method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! This is how i got it to work for now. Dont know whether it is a good solution or not. Posting the fix here for others who are  facing the same problem.

i renamed the `ToString()` override method to `MvcHtmlString ToHtml()` and returned `MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString())` instead of raw html as string.

Now i have to call it as

```
@Html.AutocompleteFor(m => m.p_empid, m => m.p_ename)
.setUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/UserMst/GetEmployee"))
.setClass("AutoComplete").setStyle("width: 190px").ToHtml()
```

Razor renders it properly now.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you return an `MvcHtmlString` by using following:

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiText(this HtmlHelper obj) {
   string code = "<p>hi</p>";
   return MvcHtmlString.Create(code);
}
```